# Is using chained #defines to declare plain-language integer indices a good idea?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a C++ program that uses an integer value to differentiate between a large number of derived class objects.  The top-level class stores the integer in the constructor, and has a public method to query it; the idea is to make it so I can quickly tell objects apart when I store them in an array using pointers typed to their top-level class.

I'm using #defines to provide plain-English names for some of the IDs; I want to be able to reference them from (my) memory without the added computational load of using string-based identifiers to find them.  I'm reluctant to make a completely static declaration in case I want to add or change identifiers later (for example, some are allocated by block, and I may someday need to increase the block size).  I've started using #define to increment the index by one.

I think examples of what I'm doing might be easier:

```
#define OBJ_FRED              0
#define OBJ_CATHY             OBJ_FRED + 1
#define OBJ_JOE               OBJ_CATHY + 1
#define OBJ_TRIPLETS_START    OBJ_JOE + 1
#define OBJ_NANCY             OBJ_TRIPLETS_START + 3
    ...
// Note that there will potentially be a lot of these.
```

My question is this: will the preprocessor substitute all occurrences of OBJ_NANCY with "0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3" or is it actually evaluating the #defines as it goes along?  If it does just substitute the text, should I be concerned that there may be a point at which the preprocessor or compiler will encounter a problem because the #define is too long?  I looked around and couldn't find a straight answer to either question.  I'm using MS Visual C++ 2015 if it matters.

I'm asking partly out of curiosity, and partly because I'll likely end up with a lot of these and I don't want to have to go back later and change all of them to static values.

Comment: No. Please use a `enum class`  or at the very least a set of `const int`s - *please* don't use pre-processor macros (`#define`).

Comment: As already mentioned, using an `enum` is best.  If sticking with #define, you'll want to use parens around the values (`#define OBJ_CATHY (OBJ_FRED + 1)`) to avoid issues in expressions, and it is common to base all IDs off of a base value (`#define OBJ_JOE (OBJ_FRED + 2)`), rather then successive increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question as asked, yes the preprocessor will substitute `OBJ_NANCY` with `0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3`.   That's what the processor does - it expands macros and does text substitution.

However, the processor is only one phase of compilation.   Although (strictly speaking) not required to, later phases of compilation will typically evaluate constant expressions e.g. turn `0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3` into `6`, rather than leaving the evaluation to be done at run time.   It is a pretty basic optimisation, and most decent-quality compilers implement it (albeit, possibly as an optional optimisation).

There are implementation-specific limits on the size of code statements (the standards describe lower bounds on those limits).   A consequence is that there are limits on the size of a macro expansion.   In practice, it is rarely a problem - the limits most implementations support are related to available memory.   And, if you are running into those limits, macro expansion is the least of your problems.

As others have said in comments (and another answer), you would be better off using an enumerated type.

You might want to look at your class design.   A need for a base class to contain a field that identifies its derived classes is known as a "code smell" - something that is probably unwanted, and for which there are often better alternatives.    Even if, sometimes, the smell is tolerable.

Comment: It's more about identifying the specific object than the derived class.  What I'm trying to avoid is allocating a large number of objects by name inside the container class; I want to be able to easily iterate through them to do many top-level functions.  The ID is needed so that I (the person) can keep them straight when looking for particular objects.

As I noted elsewhere, I didn't know about enum; I'm reading up on it and it looks like it'll simplify things quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This is much better accomplished using an enumerated type:

```
enum {
    OBJ_FRED, OBJ_CATHY, ...
};
```

It's cleaner, less-error-prone, and easier to read.

Comment: I did not know about that type, thanks for the insight.